# @synchronized in a static method

Tags: objective-c, thread-safety, synchronized

In Objective-C, you can declare a block as being synchronized on some object by using the `@synchronized` construct. It would look something like this:

```
@synchronized (self) {
    // Do something useful
}
```

However, I'm curious what exactly `self` is referring to when you have a static method (`+` instead of `-`). I tried looking through the Apple docs, and they allude to it being OK, but don't really explain it. I know it works, I'm just curious what it means.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`self` inside of a class (static) method refers to the class object.

Comment: Thank you. I know there was something simple I was missing.

Comment: Beware that @synchronized(self) in a class method can be dangerous because for sub classes self is a different object (class) so there still can be concurrent access to the method between those two classes

Answer (score 13):

In Objective-C `self` is determined by context. In an instance method, that would be the instance being called. In a static method, it would be the class object itself (i.e. the result of `[self class]` in an instance method)

Answer (score 0):

With the answers above, just keep in mind that if one thread calls an instance method using @synchronized (self), and another thread calls a class method using @synchronized (self), no synchronisation will happen between the two calls, because they are using different objects for synchronisation.